# SQL Find customers X booking

Tags: sql

Have a table called cust (as c) which is a list of all bookings from oldest to newest and contains the following columns:

clientid, bookref, tourno, book_date

I'm trying to find customers that have booked for the first, second, third, fourth and fifth time using this pre-made SQL:

```
    select c.clientid as ClientID, c.bookref as BookRef, left(c.tourno,6) as TourRef, t.place as Product, c.book_date as BookDate, c.paxnumb as Pax, c.tourcost as Revenue,
iif(c.book_date = fb.fbdate,'Y','N') as FirstBook, s.name as Source

from (select clientid, bookref, tourno, book_date, paxnumb, tourcost, sourceid from cust) as c
inner join (select tourno, place from tourlist) as t on c.tourno = t.tourno
inner join (select id, name from source) as s on c.sourceid = s.id
inner join (select clientid, min(created_date) as fbdate from custhist group by clientid) as fb on c.clientid = fb.clientid

where c.book_date between '2017-01-01' and '2019-09-30'

group by ClientID, BookRef, TourRef, Product, BookDate, Pax, Revenue, FirstBook, Source
Having FirstBook = 'Y'
order by BookRef asc
```

This returns a table with a "Y" or "N" flag if the bookref is that clientid's first booking. So this is my starting off point, I end up with a list of 42,000 clients that made a first booking from Jan 1st 2017 to September 30th 2019.

Of those 42,000 clients, how do I find out what their 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th bookings were, if they exist?

Thanks!

Comment: Why all those "plain SELECT" sub-queries? Simply JOIN the tables and select the columns you want.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: Which database oracle or sql server or etc?

Comment: It's Advantage SQL server, thanks.

Comment: I have not that much experience but `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` may helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You need row_number() over partitioning by the orderdate in a group by as per clientid with desc order of max 5 records per each group

```
 select c.clientid as ClientID, c.bookref as BookRef, left(c.tourno,6) as TourRef, t.place as Product, c.book_date as BookDate, c.paxnumb as Pax, c.tourcost as Revenue,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by c.book_date order by c.book_date desc) rn, 
iif(c.book_date = fb.fbdate,'Y','N') as FirstBook, s.name as Source

from (select clientid, bookref, tourno, book_date, paxnumb, tourcost, sourceid from cust) as c
inner join (select tourno, place from tourlist) as t on c.tourno = t.tourno
inner join (select id, name from source) as s on c.sourceid = s.id
inner join (select clientid, min(created_date) as fbdate from custhist group by clientid) as fb on c.clientid = fb.clientid

where c.book_date between '2017-01-01' and '2019-09-30'

group by ClientID, BookRef, TourRef, Product, BookDate, Pax, Revenue, FirstBook, Source
Having rn<=5
order by BookRef asc
```

Comment: Hi Himanshu, I've been searching online and seen multiple examples of using Rownumber in conjunction with over, so this looks promising, however Advantage is telling me I'm missing "FROM" after the definitions in my SELECT statement - the cursor jumps to the "over (partition" part of the query.

Comment: Can you post the whole error i guess some syntax issue